# How to import a repo along with its Pull Requests from bitbuket to github

Tags: github, bitbucket, pull-request

I want to import my bitbucket repo to GitHub with all active pull requests and I just tried GitHub import repo functionality but it not importing pull requests.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, so I have created an automated process to move all Bitbucket Pull requests to Github issues.

https://github.com/mashayev/bitbucket-pull-request-migration

It will create the same PR with the same PR ID in Github with the below information:

```
Full Diff - <Here it will create a link to the diff between master and 
destination branch>
Author: <Name>
Reviewers: <Reviewers name 1>, <Reviewers name 2>
Approvers: <Approvers name 1>, <Approvers name 1>
Source Branch: <Branch name>
Destination Branch: master
Closed On: 2021-09-19T08:47:04.149338+00:00
Status: MERGED / OPEN

added <PR title / description>
```

There is no easy way to create same pull request from BB to Github, but this process helps to align all BB PRs to Github issue with the full PR info and it keeps the same PRs index.

Answer (score 0):

Pull requests are not part of git protocol, they are feature/entity of git platform (same stands for issues, wiki, ...).

I'm unaware that someone had built migration solution.

GitHub has pull requests exposed to API https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/ .
Bitbucket probably has similar API.

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/mandiwise/5954bbb2e95c011885ff [well, i don't know more about bitbucket but i hope this helps][1]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer but URL said 404, can you please check and update the gist URL.

Comment: try the link again.Thanks